# Bad state: Snapshot has neither data nor error in flutter when using StreamBuilder and Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm adding data from Firestore to a `Stream` from `StreamBuilder`, but I'm getting the following error:

> Exception has occurred. StateError (Bad state: Snapshot has neither data nor error

My code.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  AppState? estado;

  static String? userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
  static final userColeccion = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

  var groupfav = ' ';
  Stream<QuerySnapshot>? taskGroup;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getGroupFavData();
  }

  void getGroupFavData() async {
    var groupFavData = await userColeccion.doc("$userID").get();
    var groupfav = groupFavData.data()!['groupfav'];

    taskGroup = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("groups")
        .doc(groupfav) // pass the obtained value
        .collection("task")
        .snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    estado = Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: true);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Home"),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: taskGroup,
        builder: (
          BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
        ) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text("error");
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }
          var data = snapshot.requireData;

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.size,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text("${data.docs[index]['titulo']}"),
                  subtitle: Text("${data.docs[index]['contenido']}"),
                  onTap: () {},
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                    color: Colors.red[200],
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looking at your issue, I see that 1) you need to get the data of the document BEFORE you start listening on that document, which is normal, so you want to do a call first to the collection, get the document, then listen on the document's collection called **task**, which makes sense. Your issue is still an asynchronous issue. The app is rebuilding on a stream that still hasn't arrived; you have to fix the sequence of things.

You then need to switch things up a bit and do the following:

**Option #1**:
a) Use a **FutureBuilder**: this will allow you to make the async call to get the document name based on the user Id
b) After you get the document associated to that user, you want to **listen** on the stream produced by the collection called **tasks** in that document. There is where then you can hook up the **StreamBuilder**.

**Option #2**:
a) Keep things the way you have, but do a **listen** on the **taskGroup** snapshots; but keep rebuilding the list as the values arrive on that collection.

Those are my suggestions.

Here's some brief code on option 1:

```dart
// .. in your Scaffold's body:

Scaffold(
 body: FutureBuilder( // the future builder fetches the initial data
   future: userColeccion.doc("$userID").get(),
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

     if (snapshot.hasData) {
       var groupfav = snapshot.data()!['groupfav'];

       // then once the 'groupfav' has arrived, 
       // start listening on the taskGroup

       taskGroup = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("groups")
        .doc(groupfav) // pass the obtained value
        .collection("task")
        .snapshots();

       return StreamBuilder(
           stream: taskGroup,
           builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          // the rest of your code

       });
     }

     return CircularProgressIndicator();
   }
)

)
```

Option 2 would be something like:

```dart
List<Task> userTasks = [];

void getGroupFavData() async {
    var groupFavData = await userColeccion.doc("$userID").get();
    var groupfav = groupFavData.data()!['groupfav'];

    taskGroup = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("groups")
        .doc(groupfav) // pass the obtained value
        .collection("task")
        .snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
          // here populate a list of your tasks
          // and trigger a widget rebuild once you've grabbed the values
          // and display it as a list on the UI

          setState(() {

            userTasks = snapshot.docs.map((d) => Task.fromJson(d.data())).toList();
          });
 
       });
  }
```

And in your **Scaffold**, you can have a **ListView** just rendering the items on that task list, like:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: userTasks.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     // render your tasks here
  })
```

Here's a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/a430ff3cce44d984e78cbbca6b0f0b27) with some working code to illustrate my point. Run it on DartPad and you'll see how using a FutureBuilder wrapping a StreamBuilder will accomplish what you want.

If you run the above code on DartPad, you'll get the following output:

[image]

Hope those pointers take you somewhere.

Comment: What's the error you're getting so we can provide more assistance?. Either of the approaches should work, I'd like to know what you implemented and what issue you got so as to debug it and arrive at the solution.

Comment: I'm trying to learn as I'm new to flutter and dart, I've been reading many ideas, solutions and everything related to the same, but I can't adapt the code, I tried mainly with option number 2, since I don't want to use FutureBuilder anymore that it did not update the tasks on the screen when another user added them, it only updated when the user who logged in, wrote in the database, so I opted for option 2, in this one I got an error in the `snapshots() .listen` asked me to make a taskGroup `as Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?;`

Comment: The other thing is that it is not very clear to me how to populate a list of the task, I know how to do it by map, but I didn't find a solution, if you show me documentation or explain me even more how it would be, I would appreciate it! I want to absorb like a sponge.

Comment: I updated my answer, plus here's a Gist with working code (https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/a430ff3cce44d984e78cbbca6b0f0b27). Run this on **DartPad.dev** and you'll see it in action. I even created the collections and documents just like you have them so as to make it work and you can see the implementation - exactly how I explained it pretty much above.

Comment: Thank you very much! It ended up working perfectly, I only changed the futurebuilder for a StreamBuilder to be able to hear realtime changes in the favorite group if the user gets to do it and something else to fit what I need, but thank you very much for your help, in case I managed to learn a lot, like being able to nest the future and stream builders in cases like this!